# AFNetworking: encoding URL strings containing '%" output is %25

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

Using AFNetworking 2.0 - when doing a get request with NSDictionary parameters - one of my parameters contains a % in it - it seems like AFNetworking is putting 25 in front of the % when encoding the URL - is there anyway to stop this prom happening?

Comment: Hmm, rather than having AFNetworking not percent escape, perhaps you should just `stringByRemovingPercentEncoding` before you populate the dictionary, and then let AFNetworking do its thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%` is used to mark URL-encoded characters.  For example, `%20` is a space, `%3D` is `=`, etc.  You can read more about which characters get encoded, and why, [here](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm).  The percent symbol is used to URL encode other characters, so it needs to be encoded.  (Otherwise, the two subsequent characters would be interpreted incorrectly.)

So, encoding `%` as `%25` is expected behavior.  If your server isn't parsing this properly, then your server is not conforming to the standard outlined in the document I linked to above.

That said, if you really wish to override this behavior, you can do so by subclassing [`AFURLRequestSerialization`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLRequestSerialization.m), which contains all of the encoding logic.  You can review the [`requestSerializer` property on `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.2/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.html#//api/name/requestSerializer) for more details.

Comment: Thanks gents Will look at both solutions. And do some reading to find out more.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Just tried it now as I didn't have time over the weekend. I wasn't prepared to subclass to override this one issue. So I did this:            [authId stringByRemovingPercentEncoding];
That worked perfectly. AFNetworking resolves it as I need it now. Appreciate the help!